# File input output in linux

Tags: android, c, linux

I am trying to open a block file system in android in recovery mode which is currently mounted and after opening that file system i want to move the cursor location to the beginning of that block file.

```
int movecursor(const char* blockPartition)
{
    int fd_read = open(blockPartition, O_RDONLY);
    printf("fd_read=%d \n",fd_read); 

    // go to beginning
    int returncode1 = lseek(fd_read, 0, SEEK_SET);// Here it is returning -1
    printf("returncode1=%d and \n",returncode1);
}
```

Here  i am able to open the file system in read mode that is currently mounted
but when a am trying to move the cursor to beginning of that file it is returning -1 (operation not permitted).

the above code snippet is running as a android native service.

Please help me to move the cursor position at the beginning of a file system.

Comment: What is `errno` after `lseek()` returns -1? (Hint: Look up `strerror()` to make it human readable).

Comment: Also what's the value of blockPartition?

Comment: Only think I can think of is that there might be something wrong with `blockPartition`. I'm not sure which `open` function you're using, but are you sure that's supposed to take a data block and not a file name?

Comment: For open and lseek please refer below urls
http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html
http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/lseek.2.html
http://www.nesssoftware.com/home/mwc/manpage.php?page=lseek

Comment: block partition contains the location of the the block file system in device

Comment: When i am trying to lseek the file system it show me  below error

"Can't perform lseek (<blockpartition>), error=Bad file descriptor(9)"

In above error <blockpartition> contains the which block partition from /dev/block/.........

sorry i cant give you proper block partition name as per policy.

Comment: Hi, 
Thanks a lot for your reply,
Actually i found the problem and that was i am opening same file in different method that method is close the file descriptor for same block file so system is closing all file descriptor for the same that's why i am getting error 9 (bad file descriptor ).

Answer (score 0):

you can use access system call to check whether you have access rights or not before going to open the block partition.

```html
if (access(partition, F_OK | W_OK) != -1) {
        printf("%s partition is available.Continuing...\n", partition);
        /* Open the mtd device for reading and writing */
        int fd_path = open(partition, O_RDONLY);
        lseek(fd_path, 0, SEEK_SET);// or lseek64 based on your system architecture
        
}
```

In general, when "Bad File Descriptor" is encountered when your file descriptor which you  passed into the function is not valid, which has multiple possible reasons:

*The fd is already closed somewhere.
*The fd has a wrong value, which is inconsistent with the value obtained from open system call.